# Android - Activity continues running while rotations are going on

Tags: android, android-asynctask, screen-rotation

In my activity, I have a inner class called `A` extends `AsyncTask`. I don't want activity destroys and recreates again when device is rotated. I want it keep running. I have read this link [RotationAsync](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/blob/master/Rotation/RotationAsync/src/com/commonsware/android/rotation/async/RotationAsync.java)
.They use a static class of AsyncTask. I have declared many variables in my activity, so if i use static class , I can not use variables of activity. Is there another way to do like link above without using static class of `AsyncTask`? Thanks for your answers. Sorry if my english has some mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent your Activity to restart using this settings on the Manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
```

After doing that, you can manage the changes using this code

```
@Override public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

// Checks the orientation of the screen
if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    //do something here
} else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
    //do something here
}
```

}

For more info, you can read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: Thanks. But i will use this way as last solution :(

Comment: No problem. One tip, look at the link i post, it could be useful also if you do not use this way because it shows how to retain data before the app rotates.

Answer (score 0):

To preserve your variables, you can save them into a Bundle and reload the state of your Activity when it is recreated.  This should get you started: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#SavingActivityState

Comment: My activity play mp3 file and display a image in a set of images. How can it save to when i rotate, it continues play mp3 file, not play again?

Comment: You should probably be using a Service to manage the playing of the MP3, and the Activity can tell the Service when to start and stop.  Take a look at IntentService, which is the easiest one to implement: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html